# Passing a variable inside a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a variable that will include another variable.

```
Example:
var options_id = ...
```

where 'id' is created dynamically through another variable so that the result could be

```
var options_1 = ...
var options_2 = ...
etc.
```

The 'id' is declared dynamically like this:

```
var id = itemid;
```

What would be the syntax to include the 'id' variable in the variable

```
var options_id
```

?

Comment: You can't specify the name of variable dynamically on declaration instead of this you can crate an array and push the variable value into it.

Comment: why not use an array of options ?

Comment: @MimiEAM, we are on same boat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using an object instead? You could do:

```
var id = itemid;
var options = {};
options['id'] = …;
```

Then access it using:

```
options.id
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what your looking for:

```
window['options_' + id] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that there is an `Object` in JS for that purpose.

For example:

```
var options = new Object();

var options.id = 'foo';
```

or if you want to use numeric indices then you can resort to `Array`